Populating one sheet by comparing the values of two other sheets in excel
Im trying to create a workbook that will compare the first two sheets, and then populate the third sheet with the values from the second sheet that dont appear in the first sheet.  Im doing this to try and make a common work process much more time efficient.  I'm kinda newish to excel so i apologize if this is actually trivial.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Could you provide a sample about the problem?

Set Sheet3.A1 to be
=IF(NOT($Sheet1.A1=$Sheet2.A1),$Sheet2.A1,"EQUAL")
... then Copy that cell (CTRL+C), then select all cells (in Sheet3) that has content in the first two sheets and paste (CTRL+V) to fill the formula (above) into the relevant portion of Sheet3.
Note; paste into ALL cells might be tempting, but may well create 'out of memory' problems; better paste only into a limited area of cells. Also avoid having A1 selected.
You may then set conditional formatting to e.g. subdue "EQUAL" to a light grey text.
